# Exponential Equation Prob

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponentiation

$$4^x + 4^y = 10$$
$$4^x - 4^y = 8$$
$$2^x . 2^y = ?$$
I couldn't understand this problem, also i couldn't solve the problems which like this. So I want to learn how to solve this problems are. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Funny that the exact same question was asked last week (deleted since): [How do i fix this equation $4x^x + 4x^y = 10$, $ 4x^x - 4x^y = 8$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2284009/how-do-i-fix-this-equation-4xx-4xy-10-4xx-4xy-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding and subtracting the equations.

Adding we get $2\times4^x=18\implies4^x=3^2\implies2^{2x}=3^2\implies (2^x)^2=3^2$.Taking square root $2^x=3$

Subtracting we get,$2\times4^y=2\implies 4^y=4^0\implies y=0$.So,$2^y=2^0=1$

So,now, just plug in the values of $x$ and $y$ into $2^x\cdot2^y=3\cdot1=3
$

Comment: Minor correction: $2(4^y) = 2 \Rightarrow 4^y = 1 \Rightarrow y = 0$.

Comment: @Dragonite Fixed...thanks!!

Comment: Ah I forgot a thing to add into my question: $2^x.  2^y$

Comment: can u edit ur answer?

Comment: @Gomon Done editing

Comment: I didn't understand nothing. I've tried to finding x and y and got x = 3 y = 1

Comment: @Gomon How did you get it?!

Comment: I wrote the equation as $2$ and i've got x = 3 and y = 1

Comment: so according to my teacher : $2^x = 3$ and $ 2^y = 1$

Comment: he took square root  both sides. Idk how did you get that answer If you edit that ill be happy

Comment: can someone help me?

Comment: @Gomon Changed the whole thing...You should get it now...

Comment: @Gomon I was solving individually for $x$ and $y$...But in your case it is not necessary to explicitly find them...So,leave it and try to understand my new solution...Hope it helps.If it helps upvote and accept my answer.

Comment: Yh it helped me. Thanks

Comment: @Gomon Good...Nice to help you!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

First add the two equations to help find $x$.

Then subtract the two equations to help find $y$.